# Can Outlook automatically create links for network mapped drives?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink

When I type (or paste) a hyperlink into an email I am composing, Outlook automagically creates a link, like so:

https://www.neatorama.com/

I would like Outlook to do the same for a path to a mapped network drive:

M:\Documents\Whatever

I am aware that I can create a link manually when composing the email, but I want Outlook to recognize M:\ in a similar way it does https:/

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Has your issue be resolved? If so, it's recommended to mark the helpful post :)

Comment: The ultimate answer is that Outlook cannot automatically create links for mapped network drives (like it does for http://). The answers contain helpful work arounds. So I don't know if the issue has been resolved. What is best to do here?

Comment: It's recommeded to mark the better workaround to answer, which would also benefit others find it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience, maybe we could try to ***right-click*** the file that we would like to share in your location and drag it to your message directly, so that Outlook would prompt "create Hyperlink Here", just click it and there would be a link to this file in your message automatically.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you mean by "create a link manually," so if this is old information for you then I apologize.

If you add the protocol and then the path, Outlook will make it a link when you hit space at the end.

Try:

```
file://M:\documents\whatever
```

Notice that the protocol is followed by the forward "internet slashes" but the rest of the path is using windows file-path backslashes. Also note that you will need to type `%20` instead of spaces if they occur. The easy way to paste this is is to paste it, prepend "file://" and then delete the last letter, retype the last letter and then hit space to trigger auto-link generation in Outlook

If the recipient also has "M:" mounted to a different share or location, then `\documents\whatever` will be relative to *their* mount point. And if they have nothing mounted as "M:" then the link will not work for them.

Comment: I often link directory locations to my boss and co-workers this way, as we are all on the same LAN and have shared mount points set via group policy.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook will recognize `\\networkpath\xxxx` and will create a hyperlink using that. I do not believe there is a way to do it with a drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [@lost_admin answer](https://superuser.com/a/1632090/160219) that Outlook simply won't create links automatically for mapped network drive paths :( I'm throwing my hat in the ring how I get around this quickly as I agreed creating link manually is slow.

Option 1: highlight text, Ctrl+K to bring up 'Insert Hyperlink' window

Option 2: AutoCorrect

1. Outlook, File, Options, Mail, Spelling and Autocorrect, AutoCorrect Options
2. In `Replace:` field type `M:\`
3. In `With:` field type network path to M network drive; commonly `\\ServerName\ShareName` or `\\ServerIP_X.X.X.X\ShareName`
4. After pasting path to network drive file/folder, delete & replace backslash \ after `M:`. This triggers AutoCorrect to replace it, then hit enter or space at end to trigger automatic link creation. If path has space in it you'll need to enclose the whole thing in quotes, ex: `"\\Server1\AwesomeShare\I like spaces.xlsx"`