# Outlook adds "file://" to link in message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink

When a folder path to a network drive is added as a link in an Outlook message, the receiver cannot click on the link and get to open directly the folder. This because Outlook is adding "file://" to the provided link.  This question [appears here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/unable-to-open-file-path-as-hyperlink-in-outlook/7fa8bc39-416a-4d1f-b3f1-1713a32b8f86) but the answer is of no use. Interestingly, the problem happens for us on some machines and not others, which makes me think it is a setting in Outlook but I can't find it. Maybe its a windows setting.

The link is added to the message as [specified in the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1632082/can-outlook-automatically-create-links-for-network-mapped-drives/1632210#1632210).

It looks like this [question was asked and received no answer previously](https://superuser.com/questions/1801456/outlook-add-to-internal-link-in-email-file)

What can be done?

**Edit (based on comments)**

Using first method (right-click, drag, Create Hyperlink Here), this link appears in the message:

```
\\myservername\fileshares\dir1\dir2
```

Using the ctrl-K method, this link appears in the message:

```
L:\dir1\dir2
```

Either way, when clicking on the link, "file:///" is add to the beginning of the link and a dialog box appears:

```
Microsoft Outlook  
Something unexpected went wrong with this URL:  
file:///\\myservername\fileshares\dir1\dir2
```

and yes, the message is the same, including the url specified, for either method, ie. The L: is transformed to myservername. It is not a valid path.

**Edit 2**

Output of **net use** command (The words within asterisks are not the actual words, in order to anonymize)
`L:       \\prod.*org.state*.gov\fileshares\*department*     Microsoft Windows Network`

Such that the original error message is more like:
`file:///\\prod.*org.state*.gov\fileshares\*department*\dir1\dir2`

Comment: Try to create the link as [specified here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/create-or-edit-a-hyperlink-5d8c0804-f998-4143-86b1-1199735e07bf) that is: press `ctrl+k` and select the file from the dialogue box

Comment: Have you checked that the path that the `file://` path links to is actually valid and exists on the machines where it's not working? Eg do they actually have access to that path, as unless they have the same drive mappings, and permissions to that folder path then it won't work for them. I'm assuming the users are also local of course, as external users will never be able to access it since it's local to your network, and nothing to do with whether it has `file://` in the path.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have added to the question based on these

Comment: @AlLelopath what is the format of the server name (`\\MyServer\share` or `\\MyServer.domain.com\share`)? Open command prompt, and run `net use` to list the actual server path for `L:` and compare. Note that the format `file:///\\server\share\file.txt` **IS** correct for HTML format email (Outlook just used to hide it). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54549949/7411885 for some more detail.

Comment: Added output of net use command to question

Answer (score 1):

> **ISSUE**
>
> When you click on links in emails in Outlook Desktop where the path is
> to a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) or IP address you may see the
> following:
>
> - An Outlook warning dialog with the error “Something unexpected went wrong with this URL”
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> - Silent failure for the untrusted file.
>
> This issue happens after installing the Outlook Desktop July 11th
> security updates.
>
> **STATUS: RESOLUTION**
>
> > Warning: This workaround may make a computer or a network more vulnerable to attack by malicious users or by malicious software such
> > as viruses. Make sure the FQDN or IP address you add to Trusted Sites
> > is a valid URL path for your company or network.
>
> In order to ensure continued access to files on FQDN or IP address paths add those URLs to the Trusted Sites zone in accordance with Windows guidance, Intranet site is identified as an Internet site when you use an FQDN or an IP address.

From: [Outlook blocks opening FQDN and IP address hyperlinks after installing protections for Microsoft Outlook Security Feature Bypass Vulnerability released July 11, 2023](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-blocks-opening-fqdn-and-ip-address-hyperlinks-after-installing-protections-for-microsoft-outlook-security-feature-bypass-vulnerability-released-july-11-2023-4a5160b4-76d0-465b-9809-60837bbd35a8)

Comment: this is not an [answer](https://superuser.com/help/answering), it's a [comment](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: This was the answer in my case. Adding the correct `file://server.domain.com/` entry to Trusted Sites fixes the errors about links.

Comment: Adding `prod.org.state.gov` to the trusted sites is the answer. You might consider adding steps 1,2,3,4 in the link to the answer should the link ever break.